# YAML::XS error checking

Tags: perl, cpan

I am using the [YAML::XS](http://search.cpan.org/dist/YAML-LibYAML/lib/YAML/XS.pod)  CPAN module. How do I error check if it fails while loading the YAML file? The documentation says nothing

```
use YAML::XS qw/LoadFile/;
$CONFIG_DATA = LoadFile($CONFIG_FILE);
```

I want to print a meaningful message if the $CONFIG_FILE has syntax errors.

Comment: Any reason why wrapping LoadFile call in an eval {} block won't work for you?

Comment: Try introducing some syntax errors and see what it does.

Comment: @PaulAllen. Thanks for the tip, totally missed it. I have used that hack for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch the error with [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), although you're correct that the docs don't tell you that `LoadFile` will die if it encounters an error:

```
use v5.10;
use YAML::XS qw/LoadFile/;
use Data::Dumper;

my $hash = eval { LoadFile( $ARGV[0] ) };
if( $@ ) {
    say "I found an error: $@";
    }
say Dumper( $hash );
```